# Handling imbalanced data by deleting over represented rows vs. adding under represented rows

Tags: data, class-imbalance

I am currently working with a very imbalanced data set
(frauded credit card data from kaggle, which has 492 rows of frauded cards and over 280,000 rows of non-frauded cards).

As much as I know, there are 2 ways to handle imbalanced data without adjusting penalty:

- over-sampling the under-represented data - by creating a lot of copies of the frauded data
- under-sampling the over-represented data - by not using a lot of the non-frauded data

Right now I go with under-sampling (since my computer is not that strong and I do not want to waste hours for answers).

Technically what I do, is create a 50-50 dataframe, which has all of the under-represented rows and randomly selected over-represented rows.

Problem is, every time I run the notebook, the algorithms use different random okay data and there are different results. When tweaking xgboost, there are different optimal parameters every time I run the notebook.

What should I do? Should I save as csv one of the balanced df I created and call it a day? Should I creat a lot of copies from the frauded cards? What is the best way to tackle the situation?

Answer (score 1):

> Technically what I do, is create a 50-50 dataframe, which has all of the under-represented rows and randomly selected over-represented rows.

You could use a **random seed** for the selection from the non-frauded cards dataset so that every time it selects the same rows. This way you are able to track and compare the results.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random

arr = np.arange(5)  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
random.seed(1)  # Reset random state
random.shuffle(arr)  # Shuffle!
print(arr)
```

Just an example on how to use random seed from `numpy`, you'll have to come up with your own way to use it for your need (**suggestion**: create `arr` in `range(0, len(frauded_card))` and shuffle it, then use arr as indexes for the `frauded_card` sample to use)